# Create automatic Carousel from URL - Sencha etc

Tags: java, arrays, html, url, extjs

I have a number of *.jpg images in an "images/" URL. How can I populate the Carousel automatically from the URL without having to manually load and re-edit the array each time I upload new pictures?

I couldn't find anything on previous posts to help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a web service that can scan the images folder and return a json object of the list of files. Then use that to create your carousel items.

In very rough code, something like this (PHP Code):

```
$dir = opendir("images");
$files = array();
// get each entry
while ($name = readdir($dir)) {
  $files[] = $name;
}
echo json_encode($files);
```

Then on the client side do an AJAX request to retrieve this list and once you get it, create a carousel using this list.